# Latex beamer: get colour used in theme

Tags: beamer, color, themes

I would like to reuse colours defined by a beamer theme and the colour theme.

For example, if I use:

```
\usetheme{Berkeley}
\usecolortheme{beetle}
```

how can I find out what the colour is used in the sidebar so that I can reuse it again?

I already found this:

```
{\usebeamercolor[fg]{structure} text}
```

which is really good, but I would like to be able to not only use the colour for text but for example define it as the title colour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am pretty sure, what you are looking for is this:

[CTAN Package](https://ctan.org/pkg/beamer?lang=de) and 
[Github Project Beamer](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer)

and in your case (Beetle-Theme):

[beamercolorthemebeetle.sty](https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/blob/master/base/themes/color/beamercolorthemebeetle.sty)

where all colors are defined like this:

```
% Copyright 2007 by Till Tantau
% Copyright 2015 by Vedran Mileti\'c, Joseph Wright
%
% This file may be distributed and/or modified
%
% 1. under the LaTeX Project Public License and/or
% 2. under the GNU Public License.
%
% See the file doc/licenses/LICENSE for more details.

\setbeamercolor*{normal text}{fg=yellow!50!white,bg=blue!50!black}

\DeclareOption{overlystylish}
{
  \def\beamer@cta@do{
    \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=black,top=black,middle=blue!50!black]
  }
}
\ProcessOptions

\@ifundefined{beamer@cta@do}{}{\beamer@cta@do}

\mode<presentation>

\setbeamercolor*{example text}{fg=green!65!black}

\setbeamercolor*{structure}{fg=blue!25!white}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{use={structure,normal text},fg=structure.fg,bg=normal text.bg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{use={structure,normal text},fg=structure.fg,bg=normal text.bg!60!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{use={structure,normal text},fg=structure.fg,bg=normal text.bg!45!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{use={structure,normal text},fg=structure.fg,bg=normal text.bg!30!black}

\setbeamercolor*{block body}{bg=normal text.bg!90!black}
\setbeamercolor*{block body alerted}{bg=normal text.bg!90!black}
\setbeamercolor*{block body example}{bg=normal text.bg!90!black}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{parent=structure,bg=normal text.bg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor*{block title alerted}{use={normal text,alerted text},fg=alerted text.fg!75!normal text.fg,bg=normal text.bg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{use={normal text,example text},fg=example text.fg!75!normal text.fg,bg=normal text.bg!75!black}

\setbeamercolor{item projected}{fg=black}

\setbeamercolor*{sidebar}{parent=palette primary}

\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar primary}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar tertiary}{use=normal text,fg=normal text.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette sidebar quaternary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}

\setbeamercolor*{separation line}{}
\setbeamercolor*{fine separation line}{}


\mode
<all>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Great, that's exactly the file I was looking for! Thanks very much!